# How do you apply multiple textures at a time (see inside for more details)

Tags: texturing

I have a collada (.dae) file and another folder full of textures for it.

How do I apply all of those textures to the object, or is there a way to import it with the textures on it?

[image: Folder with images]

[image: Imported]